# The ASCII value of '\0' is same as ASCII value of 0?

Tags: c

I learned the ASCII value of '\0' is 0, and the ASCII value of 0 is 0x30, but when I try to print their ASCII value using printf, I get the same output:

```
printf("\'\\0\' : %d\n", '\0');
printf("\'\\0\' in hex : %x\n", '\0');
printf("0 : %d\n", 0);
printf("0 in hex: %x\n", 0);
```

output:

```
'\0' : 0
'\0' in hex : 0
0 : 0
0 in hex: 0
```

why?

Comment: It's a `NULL` byte, which is the same thing as zero.

Comment: @EvanMulawski, `'\0'` is actually `NUL`. `NULL` is a pointer. (Not that there is a difference in C, but conceptually they are different)

Comment: @Shahbaz: Oops, double-tapped the "L" by mistake. You are correct.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The ASCII character `'0'` is different than the number `0`. You are printing the integer `0` in your second pair of `printf`s instead of `'0'`.

Try this:

```
printf("'\\0' : %d\n", '\0');
printf("'\\0' in hex : %x\n", '\0');
printf("'0' : %d\n", '0');
printf("'0' in hex: %x\n", '0');
```

Also, you don't need to escape `'` inside strings. That is, `"'"` is fine and you don't need to write `"\'"`

Answer (score 13):

You confuse 0, '\0', and '0'.

The first two of these are the same thing; they just represent an `int` with value 0.

'0', however, is different, and represents an `int` with the value of the '0' character, which is `48`.

Answer (score 3):

```
printf("0 : %d\n", '0');
```

Print like this, you will get 48.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the character literal`'\0'` has value `0` and this is independent of the character set.

> (K&R2, 2.3) "The character constant '\0' represents the character with value zero, the null character. '\0' is often written instead of 0 to emphasize the character nature of some expression, but the numeric value is just 0."

Answer (score 1):

All of these answers seem to miss the point of `\0` ...

Try this:

```
printf("This line\0 might not completely appear");
```

That's the reason for `\0`

So you can define a NULL terminated string ...

```
#define TEST_STRING "Test"
```

is quite different from

```
#define TEST_STRING "Test\0"
```

the latter being useful in certain cases.

Comment: `"Test"` is a null-terminated string.

Comment: You are correct - senility must be setting in ...  #define NAME_DESC "Dog\0A four legged friend" would have been a better example, using the '\0' to 'hide' the description from standard functions and catenate a second string (the description).  I merely meant to show it has a usefulness.

Answer (score 0):

The ASCII value for '\0' is indeed 0. But '\0' is different from '0' (notice the backslash, which is the escape symbol).

Answer (score 0):

Your last line should be

```
printf("0 in hex: %x\n", '0');
```