# ASCII value = 0 and '\0'

Tags: c, ascii, null-character

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294850/the-ascii-value-of-0-is-same-as-ascii-value-of-0).
But when I tried:

```
  printf("before null %c after null\n", 0);  // (ASCII=0) != '\0' ??
```

instead of getting:

```
before null
```

I got:

```
before null   after null
```

So my question is:
  Is ASCII value 0 actually equal to '\0'?

Comment: Yes, but printf is printing your string piece by piece, so it doesn't end at the middle `\0`. It prints `"before null "`, then the `%c` then `" after null"`.

Comment: Yes, you can always comment in your own question and/or own answers. And even on responses on your own questions.

Comment: Thanks for answering.
But I've tried `printf("before null \0 after null\n");` and the output is: `before null `
What's the difference between these two?

Comment: @iamsuperwen It is printf that evaluates the "%c" and decides what to do with the corresponding value (0). The NUL is *out-of-band* with respect to a string (similar to how SQL placeholders prevent SQL injection). Compare with `printf("before null %c after null \0 after silly null in string\n", 0);`.

Comment: user286 said what I wanted to say better :-)

Comment: Similarly, `printf("%cn", '\\')` outputs `\n` (two characters), not a newline.

Comment: Note that if you fed the output of the code fragment in the question through a program that prints all bytes visibly, you'd find that the output included a null byte, which doesn't display as a visible character (though your output seems to show a 'blank' where the null byte is printed).  You could use `od -c`, `cat -v`, `xxd -g`, and no doubt other programs to see that null byte.

Answer (score 5):

> Is ASCII value 0 actually equal to `\0`?

Yes

---

The differences in how the strings are stored in memory and handled by functions like `printf()` are important.

```
"before null %c after null\n"
"before null \0 after null\n"
```

Both are stored in memory with an implicit `\0` terminator at the end. The fact that the second has an explicit `\0` character in the middle changes things.

`printf()` will scan the string until "*the end*", printing components as it goes... in C "*the end*" typically means until the first `\0` / *nul* character.

With the first variant, `printf()` copies characters to the output until it reaches the `%c` directive, at which point it looks at the arguments that were given to the function... it might find that you gave `'\0'`, or it might find that you gave `'+'` - either way, it copies this to the output. It'll then continue copying characters to the output, seeking "*the end*" of the string.

With the second variant, `printf()` will start copying characters to the output, will find "*the end*" (denoted by the `\0`), and stop.

If you were to use `snprintf()`, then the results / outputs would contain the following: (again, with implicit `\0` termination)

```
"before null \0 after null\n"
"before null "
```

If you were to subsequently print both of these, they would *look* the same, but the memory content would be different.

However, the output of `printf()` is the terminal (or a file)... what happens for `\0` depends on your terminal emulator... it might simply not be shown, it might be displayed as a space, or it may have a funny box symbol...

The important thing to note, is that this occurs at run time - not compile time.

Comment: Yep, that looks like just what happens. Thanks for you comments.

Answer (score 3):

That's because `printf` is NOT actually replacing `"Hello %s", "World"` with `"Hello World"` then print. No. **It does not concatenate**.

Rather, **it actually prints each character alone in order**, and when it encounters an argument, it starting printing each character from it directly too without concatenating.

If you ever tried to print a single `null` character using `putchar()`, You'd notice that it prints a space instead, that's why `printf` prints a space too based on it. (Note that It'll print **nothing** on other systems like Linux).

**Sample code of how printf actually work.**

---

```
const char * x;
// while the current char != '\0'
while (*format)
{
    // if the current char == '%'
    if (*format == '%')
    {
        // increment the pointer so we can point to the next char and skip printing '%'
        switch (*(++format)) // then switch that next char (specifier).
        {
        case 'c':
            putchar(va_arg(args, char)); // if the argument is null, then it's putchar(0);
            break;
        case 's':
            // regular operation of printing a string argument.
            x = va_arg(args, const char*);
            while (*x) putchar(*x++);
            break;
        }
        // skips the format specifier so we don't print it (e.g 's', 'c'..)
        *format++;
    }
    // else: isn't a format specfier.
    else
       // print the current char (pointer) of the original string
        putchar(*format++); // increments it for the next operation.
}
va_end(args);
```

So returning to your question, It will print each character and when it comes to the argument `0` which is **null**, `putchar()` will either put a space or nothing based on your system.

You can say that `printf` arguments don't really have any relationship with the original string to terminate it, they don't know each other. Like when you `printf("Hello %s, from SO!", "World");`**,** `"World"` is actually terminated at the end with `\0`, but it will terminate just itself, not the other `, from SO!`.

And **Yes**, `0` is `'\0'`. they're the same character.

Comment: If `putchar(0)` puts a space character, your system is broken. It outputs a NUL character (on ASCII systems). How that affects terminals or applications is another matter.

Comment: My system isn't broken. It'll print a space on Windows systems and nothing on Linux. based on the OP code result, I tried to answer him as it looks he's using Windows system.

Comment: Then that's the Windows terminal *converting* the NUL to a space. If you redirect the output to a file and look at it with a hex editor, you'll find a NUL, not a space.

Answer (score 1):

`printf` will not terminate the printf format-string at that character position for the `%c` *format-specifier* when given values `0` or `'\0'`. Instead, the terminal output for the `nul` will generally be a placeholder (e.g. a `space` or the like)

However you can insert a `nul` into the string and then output the string using the `%s` *format-specifier* and see that in fact *decimal* 0 is actually the ASCII value for the equivalent ASCII *character* `'\0'` and will terminate the string at the point of the *nul-character* (see: [www.ASCIItable.com](http://www.asciitable.com/)), e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FMT "before null %c after null\n"

int main (void) {

    char buf[sizeof FMT * 2];

    puts (FMT);

    sprintf (buf, FMT, 0);
    printf ("using 0 : '%s'", buf);
    putchar ('\n');

    sprintf (buf, FMT, '\0');
    printf ("using \\0: '%s'", buf);
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/str_printf_null
before null %c after null

using 0 : 'before null '
using \0: 'before null '
```

Comment: "_printf will not output a nul to stdout using the %c format-specifier and values 0 or '\0'_" - seems to for me...?

Comment: Well, that may indicate that how an OS handles output of a *nul-character* with `%c` is *implementation defined*. I tested on Linux. I'll also test on windoze and see if they implement it the same. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Hmm - I get "**Zoinks! You've taken a wrong turn.**" from your link. I also tested on Win7 and get the same output. How do I look at your code?

Comment: Oh yes, yes... We are saying the same thing, but differently. I'm not saying the `%c` won't output the byte, what I'm saying is that it will not have the effect of terminating the `printf` *format-string* at that character position. It simply uses a placeholder for the `nul` within the output.

Comment: @Attie - I updated in hopefully a more articulate manner to reflect the actual behavior.

Comment: ah, gotcha, thanks for clarifying... also see my answer regarding `snprintf()` followed by `printf()`