# Why does changing array elements in a loop delete the array

Tags: c

So i was running some tests and there was strange behavior going on whenever I tried to change a character from a to 0. Instead of changing the element in the array like I expected, the entire array was deleted. Here is what I used to debug

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char test[] = "aa432aa";
    for(int i = 0; i<7; i++){
        printf("%s\n", test);
        if(test[i] == 'a'){
            test[i] = 0;
            printf("an a\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("not a\n");
        }
    }
    printf("%s", test);
}
```

And here is the output:

```
aa432aa                                                                                    
an a                                                                                       
                                                                                           
an a                                                                                       
                                                                                           
not a                                                                                      
                                                                                           
not a                                                                                      
                                                                                           
not a                                                                                      
                                                                                           
an a                                                                                       
                                                                                           
an a
```

Comment: Are you trying to set it to the digit zero? Use `'0'` instead of `0`

Comment: When you do: `test[i] = 0;` instead of `test[i] = '0'`, you are setting the string _terminator_ character which is 0x00 and _not_ 0x30, the ASCII code for `'0'` [as you probably want]. So, the final `printf` will stop much earlier than you expect because it stops when it sees 0x00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments you should use `test[i] = '0'` not `test[i] = 0`, because `'0'` is the `0` **character**, while `0` is equal to `'\0'`. When printing, `'\0'` is treated as the final character of the string, so that's why, after changing the first `'a'` to `0`(`'\0'`), you're not able to print it correctly.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char test[] = "aa432aa";
    for(int i = 0; i<7; i++){
        printf("%s\n", test);
        if(test[i] == 'a'){
            test[i] = '0'; // Here!
            printf("an a\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("not a\n");
        }
    }
    printf("%s", test);
}
```

Output:

```
aa432aa
an a
0a432aa
an a
00432aa
not a
00432aa
not a
00432aa
not a
00432aa
an a
004320a
an a
0043200
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because ASCII value `0` is actually equal to `\0` and `\0` is indicating the end of string in `C`. In the for loop when you set `test[i] = 0;`, this means it will convert the value of the `test` variable into `"\0a432aa"`. So when you are trying to print it, it found an ending character at the beginning and do not able to print anything. To clear the idea, try to print a string like `"xx\0a432aa"`, and it will only print `"xx"`.

I think you are trying to put `'0'` instead of `'a'`. If that is the case, your code should be like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("\'\\0\' : %d\n", '\0');
    printf("0 : %d\n", 0);
    
    char t[] = "xx\0a432aa";
    printf("%s\n", t);

    char test[] = "aa432aa";
    for(int i = 0; i<7; i++){
        printf("%s\n", test);
        if(test[i] == 'a'){
            test[i] = '0';
            printf("an a\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("not a\n");
        }
    }
    printf("%s", test);
}
```

I also add 4 initial lines to give you intuition about the problem you are facing here. For further understanding you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50771351/ascii-value-0-and-0) post from stackoverflow.