# Is '\0' in the middle of a string can be recognized as the end of a string in C?

Tags: c, string

I know in C `'\0'` is always at the end of a string, but is `'\0'` always mark the end of a string?

Just like "1230123" can be recognized as "123"?

<sup>*One edition of the question used the notation `'/0'` instead of `'\0'`.*</sup>

Comment: Its not '/0' but '\0'.

Comment: `\0` is not the same character as `0`.

Comment: String definition in [G4G](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strings-in-c-2/)  : 

Strings are defined as an array of characters. The difference between a character array and a string is the string is terminated with a special character `\0`. There is an extra terminating character which is the Null character `\0` used to indicate termination of string which differs strings from normal character arrays.

Answer (score 2):

A byte with the value 0 by definition marks the end of a string.  So if you had something like this:

```
char s[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0', 'd', 'e', 'f', '\0' };
printf("%s\n");
```

It would print `abc`.

This is different from `"1230123"` where the 4th character in the string is not the value 0 but the character `'0'`, which has an ASCII code of 48.

Comment: Great answer, and i suggest to add [link](https://ascii.cl/)  to [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) table that illustrate `\0` as ASCII code of NULL and 48 as ASCII code of `0`.

Comment: @EsmaeelE But, it is unlikely that when any user runs the program, the program will have the locale for the C standard library's string functions is set to ASCII. Programs that depend on characters having specific character codes (other than 0) are, um—to put it kindly—"overly specific".

Answer (score 2):

The null terminating character is represented as `\0` and not `/0` and it always mark end of string because, in C, **strings are actually one-dimensional array of characters terminated by a null character** `\0`.

This

```
char s[] = "1230123";
```

is same as this

```
char s[] = {'1', '2', '3', '0', '1', '2', '3', '\0'};
                            |                    |
                    This is character '0'        |
                    whose decimal value is 48    |
                                                 |
                                     This is null terminating character
                                     whose decimal value is 0
```

Check this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int x,y,z;
    char s1[] = "1230123";
    char s2[] = {'1','2','3','\0','4','5','6','\0'};
    printf ("%s\n", s1);
    printf ("%s\n", s2);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1230123
123      <======= The characters after null terminating character is not printed.
```

Answer (score 2):

A *string literal* can have a `'\0'` in the middle.

A *string* only has a `'\0'` at the end.

`'\0'` is the *null character* and has a value of 0. `'0'` is the character zero.
See [value of '\0' is same ... 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11294850/2410359)

---

C has, as part of the language, *string literals*.

The two *string literals* below have a size of 8: the 7 you see plus the 1 not explicitly coded trailing *null character* `'\0'`.

```
"abc-xyz"    // size 8
"abc\0xyz"   // size 8
```

C, as part of the standard library, defines a *string*.

> A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.

Many `str...()` functions only work with the data up to the first *null character*.

```
strlen("abc-xyz")  --> 7
strlen("abc\0xyz") --> 3
```

Comment: I liked that you used string syntax for showing the use of '\0' in the middle of a string, rather than array of chars syntax, like the other answers. Somehow, using string syntax makes it more clear that '\0' has the same "citizen range" as any other escape sequences.